# Is there a way to programatically set the printer properties in Windows?

Tags: windows, script, printer

As a paper saving drive throughout the organization, we plan to set 2 page printing as default setting on all the Windows machines.

I would like to contribute to this by writing a small script that can do that for all the machines, maybe send an email to all the users, and let them run the batch file.

Is that possible? I have no knowledge about Windows scripting. I program in Java for my living.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yeah well, your users will print everything at the default 2-pages a sheet and then print everything again at 1-page a sheet, adding 50% to the amount of paper used rather than saving paper.

Answer (score 1):

Windows printer properties are stored in the registry.  You could try exporting the necessary keys and setting them on the target machine.  This assumes the same model printer is in use on source and target systems.

```
Here's the key to start looking for Windows XP.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print
```

Comment: I understand that the properties are stored at this place, but is there any link that you know where I can get started to write a script to create a printer profile and activate it as the default one, after running the script.

Comment: You can use the regedit GUI or the reg command http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html to to export a file.  I would edit it down to just the values you want to add/modify and import it on the target machine.

Comment: Also Remember: Printer settings are driver specific so the printer must be of the same model on the target for this to work.